# Apply a mask to an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, uiimage, mask

i found a tutorial that explain how apply a mask on an UIImage, but i have a problem.

this is the link:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html

If i apply a mask to an image taken by a picker with "picker.alowsEditing=YES" the mask is applyed well and the background of the image is the same color of the application's backgroung, and is good.

But if the option is "picker.alowsEditing=NO" when i apply the mask the image's background become black.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i undstend that the problem is the alpha layer.
If an image have not an alpha layer can't use the mask, otherwise the image background will be colored  Black.

To add an alpha layer (layer with alpha channel) to an image i found an userfull guide here:

http://pastie.org/418627